# How to stop method execution defined in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one problem in JS, please help me to resolve this.. I have two methods they are simultaneously executing one after other.. I have to stop them after second click on image.
Below is my JS code

I am calling fadeIn(img1, img2, img3) after first click on image then some animation will be goes on, once I click second time the whole animation(method execution) should be stopped.

```
var t1 = 0;
var t2 = 0;
function fadeIn(img1, img2, img3) {
$(imgIdForClick_1).addClass('animated pulse');
$('#cashBar1').addClass('animated pulse');
$('#cashBarDec1').addClass('animated pulse');

var t1 = setTimeout(function() {
    fadeOut(img1, img2, img3);
    if (clickCount_1 >= 2) {
        alert("clicked 1");
        return false;
    }
 }, 500);

 //t1 = setTimeout(fadeOut, 500);
};
function fadeOut(img11, img22, img33) {
$(imgIdForClick_1).removeClass('animated pulse');
$('#cashBar1').removeClass('animated pulse');
$('#cashBarDec1').removeClass('animated pulse');
var t2 = setTimeout(function() {
    fadeIn(img11, img22, img33);
    if (clickCount_1 >= 2) {
        alert("clicked 2");
        return false;
    } 
}, 500);

//t2 = setTimeout(fadeIn, 500);
};
```

By below code I am calling this snippet in first click

```
imgId1 = $('#img1');
        imgId2 = $('#cashBar1');
        imgId3 = $('#cashBarDec1');
        fadeIn(imgId1, imgId2, imgId3);
```

After second click
clickCount_1 varibale will be 2

```
clearTimeout(t1);
    clearTimeout(t2);
```

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skBK7/ its exactly same like this example, please check. I am using some plugins so I can't create fiddle of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/skBK7/49/). Click on the image to stop animation.
I have added a `flag` that would be checked upon the call of the function, and if the value is `true` then and then only the functions would be called. The `flag` would be set to `false` when clicked on image, so the function would be called no longer.

code:

```
var animate = true;
function fadeIn() {
    $('#pulseDiv').find('div#advisersDiv').delay(400).addClass("pulse");
    if(animate == true)
    {        
        setTimeout(fadeOut,1000);
    }
};

function fadeOut() {
    $('#pulseDiv').find('div#advisersDiv').delay(400).removeClass("pulse");
    if(animate == true)
    {
        setTimeout(fadeIn,1000);
    }    
};
fadeIn();

$('#image').click(function(){
    animate = false;
    alert('now the animation will stop');
});
```